# Request for Feed The Future, Baseline Population Based Survey - Ethiopia

Tags: data-request

I am working on an MSc thesis titled women empowerment in agricultural productivity and marketed surplus: In case of Ethiopia. [How can I access the data of Feed The Future, Baseline Population Based Survey - Ethiopia](http://essp.ifpri.info/files/2014/12/FTF-baseline-report-FINAL-for-website.pdf) collected in 2013 and is there a second wave of the same data?